# How to find the length of an array referenced by a pointer inside another array?

Tags: c++

```
int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int array2[] = {6, 7, 8, 9};

int *arrays[] = {array1, array2};
```

How to get length of the array1 and array2 from `arrays`? (`arrays[0]` length and `arrays[1]` length)

Comment: Can I interest you in our lord and savior, [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? (But jokes aside, is there a reason you're insisting on C-style arrays here instead of nice C++ vectors or `std::array`s?)

Comment: Save yourself a lot of pain here and use std::vector

Comment: pointers are not arrays. Arrays have a size, pointers to the first element of an array not. There are uncountable variations of this same problem, `std::vector` answers them all ;)

Comment: Prefer `std::array` if the size is fixed and set at compile time. That's an array that knows its size, and stays knowing its size (i.e. cannot decay to a pointer). There is no point incurring the dynamic allocation of `vector` if dynamic size is not needed.

Comment: @underscore_d: that won't work here -- you can't declare an array of `std::array`s of different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Not.
Pointers to datatype (`int`e.g.), which arrays decay to in this context, do not know about the size. It is similar to the problem that you cannot find the size within a function.
This means you need to know it, e.g. because you have in a second array the size information, or like in the case of 0-terminated characters sequences, a way to dermine the length from the content.

In order to be helpful, I join those (e.g. in the comments here), to use a C++ container class, most prominently the `std::vector`.